# How to avoid cmd from popping up and closing when subprocess.popen() is executed in an executable built with py2exe?

Tags: python, python-2.7, py2exe

I built an executable with py2exe. At first the command prompt popped up when I executed the program and remained open until I closed the program. I look for a solution and found something that worked.I changed a line in the setup file (http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Tutorial) code from this:

```
setup(console=['myapp.py'])
```

to this:

```
setup(windows=['myapp.py'])
```

Doing this resulted in the command prompt not opening every time I executed the program.

But the problem I'm having right now is that whenever a line of code like the following is executed (I coded a program to automatically create several windows tasks) the command prompt pops up and closes.

```
subprocess.Popen('schtasks /Create /S PC_Name /RU User /RP Password /XML XML_file, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

This doesn't happen if I run the py file, only if I use the py2exe library to build the executable file.

The application works fine, I does what it is supposed to do. I just want to stop the command prompt from popping up.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try this bad boy:

```
def run_cmd(cmd):
    fi, fo, fe = os.popen3(cmd)
    response = ""
    if fo:
        for i in fo.readlines():
            response += i
    if fe:
        for i in fe.readlines():
            response += i
    return response
```